# eclipse jena and tomcat query

Tags: eclipse, servlets, sparql, jena

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class rdf
 */
public class rdf extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public rdf() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String inputFileName = "/home/jarboox/Documentos/Eclipse/workspace/Sparql/src/tres.rdf";

        try {

              //create the reasoning model using the base
              OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();

              // use the FileManager to find the input file
              InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
              if (in == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
              }

              inf.read(in, "");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
          } 
    }

}
```

> Tomcat problem:
>
> type Informe de Excepción
>
> mensaje La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción
>
> descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no
>   pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.
>
> excepción
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una
>   excepción causa raíz
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory
>     rdf.doPost(rdf.java:55)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) causa
>   raíz
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     rdf.doPost(rdf.java:55)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) nota La
>   traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos
>   de diario de Apache Tomcat/6.0.36.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory
>   rdf.doPost(rdf.java:55)

The jena jars are not on the runtime class path of the webapp.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem :) Just had to update tomcat to recognize the .jar